# Corrupt excel from openpyxl from trailing space in worksheet property

Tags: openpyxl

"We found a problem with some content in 'xxx.xlsx'. Do you want to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."

you then get a relatively unhelpful log

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <logFileName>error064200_01.xml</logFileName>
    <summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Users\mark.nicholls\source\repos\bumblebee3\bumblebee\bumblebee.xlsx'</summary>
    <additionalInfo>
        <info>Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded.</info>
    </additionalInfo>
</recoveryLog>
```

The cause of the issue is the presence of something like..

```
<cp:lastModifiedBy xml:space="preserve">Report Service </cp:lastModifiedBy>
```

in the ooxml.

i.e. excel seems to object to the 'xml:space' attribute.

This can be triggered by code like this

```
workbook.properties.lastModifiedBy = escape.escape('Report Service ')
```

how can I prevent this happening? ok, I can trim this specific string, but I'm not sure if this is just triggered by trailing whitespace. I was hoping escape would fix it, but it seems not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so...digging into the openpyxl code, I discovered in

https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.0/openpyxl/xml/functions.py

this

```
def whitespace(node):
    if node.text != node.text.strip():
        node.set("{%s}space" % XML_NS, "preserve")
```

I don't pretend to understand how the serialisation works in the library, but it looks like if it sees any leading/trailing whitespace, it will then inject a preserve, which will then upset excel.

For the moment I'm going to 'strip' it before it goes in, but I'll probably replace it with '_' at some point, really its a bug in openpyxl, as it would seem to be impossible to insert spaces before or after a title property of a workbook.

Note:
actually i MAY not be the preserve whitespace thats upsetting excel, it may be that is fine, but the preceding/trailing spaces themselves are upsetting it, either way, stripping the data should fix it. Its logged as an issue with openpyxl.

Comment: I've logged it as an issue on the project site